# How to define FlashHelper/Component element for general authError message

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6, cakephp-2.7

After updating CakePHP from 2.6.2 to 2.7.2 I get an missing key error when the auth flash message is created. How can I define the element template for the default `authError`?

Since `SessionComponent::setFlash()` has been [deprecated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html#displaying-notifications-or-flash-messages) I added the [FlashComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/flash.html) in `app/Controller/AppController.php` and modified all Flash messages from this:

```php
// Controller
$this->Session->setFlash('Done', 'succeed');
$this->Session->setFlash('There is an error', 'failure');
$this->Session->setFlash('Please log in', 'auth');
// View (default Layout)
echo $this->Session->flash();
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
```

to this:

```php
// Controller
$this->Flash->succeed('Done');
$this->Flash->failure('There is an error');
$this->Flash->auth('Please log in');
// View (default Layout)
echo $this->Flash->render();
echo $this->Session->flash();       // keep temporarily?
echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); // keep temporarily?
```

I also copied the flash related templates from
`App/View/Elements/succeed.ctp` to
`App/View/Elements/Flash/succeed.ctp`

This is working – **but** if I am **not logged in** and try to access an admin page I get the default [authError](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::$authError) message defined in `app/Controller/AppController.php` shown **without** the according template. With debug mode 2 I get the following error:

```php
// Undefined variable: key [CORE\Cake\View\Elements\Flash\default.ctp, line 1]
// include - CORE\Cake\View\Elements\Flash\default.ctp, line 1
// View::_evaluate() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 971
// View::_render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 933
// View::_renderElement() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 1227
// View::element() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 418
// SessionHelper::flash() - CORE\Cake\View\Helper\SessionHelper.php, line 159
// include - APP\View\Layouts\default.ctp, line 142
// View::_evaluate() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 971
// View::_render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 933
// View::renderLayout() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 546
// View::render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 481
// Controller::render() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 960
// Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 200
// Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 167
// [main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 118
// Message" class="message">
```

What changes in AppController.php are necessary to get the default authError rendered with my own element template "auth"?

Here the part of the AppController.php:

```php
public $components = array(
  'Flash',
  'Session',
  'Security',
  'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish')),
    'authError' => 'My default auth error message.', // How do I have to modify this line?
    'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'welcome'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'goodbye'),
  )
);
```

And are these two lines still necessary when changing all flash messages in all Controllers to the Flash compoment and helper? Where else are they used by CakePHP?

```php
echo $this->Session->flash();
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
```

I also had a look at the [Authentication tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html). But it seems to be not up to date since `$this->Session->setFlash()` is still heavily in use...

Comment: I got this error: Error: Call to a member function success() on a non-object

Comment: @DariusVE In my code example I used `succeed` as template name, obiously you used `success`. So your error should be fixed by adding the template `App/View/Elements/Flash/success.ctp` instead...

Comment: Yesterday I fixed the issue, you need to add the `Flash` component in your components array at the AppController.php `public $components = array( 'Session', 'Flash', 'Auth');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your Auth component setting array add something like

```
'Auth' = [
    ...
    'flash' => ['element' => 'auth_error'],
    ...
]
```

then create a template named `auth_error.ctp` in your `Element/Flash` directory. In this file the only variable you use should be `$message`, because when cake calls Flash from the Auth components does not pass any other variable (i.e. the `$key` variable)

Maybe this answer is not 100% correct (so any suggestion is welcome) but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Cake itself, it is (will be) fixed in 2.7.4

See: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7379

Answer (score 0):

Just Add Flash component it will work .

```
class AppController extends Controller {

     public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar','Flash');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem, this will definitely resolve your issue. Please add the following line of code in **app/Controller/AppController.php**:

```
public $components = array('Flash');
```