# Undefined variable: key [CORE\Cake\View\Elements\Flash\success.ctp, line 1]

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I am using CakePHP 2.7.

I generated MVC code using Cake Bake.

Running the project generates the following error message:-

> Undefined variable: key [CORE\Cake\View\Elements\Flash\success.ctp, line 1]

What is causing this error?

Comment: Please show that code where you got error?then only anyone can help you.thanks.

Comment: <div id="<?php echo h($key) ?>Message" class="message success"><?php echo h($message) ?></div>

\\\lib\Cake\View\Elements\Flash\success.php

Comment: Do you know which controller action is rendering this template? Could you post that code as from what your error message is saying `$key` is not getting set.

Comment: this is my controller code 

$this->Flash->success(__('The role has been saved.'));

and error message is 
Undefined variable: key [CORE\Cake\View\Elements\Flash\success.ctp, line 1]

Comment: You need to show more code - what's relevant is how you are rending the flash message, it sounds like a mismatch between [the old way](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp#L45) (which uses the session component/helper), and [the new way](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp#L45) (which depends on the flash component/helper) - they aren't compatible. Please **edit the question** to add information - do not write comments.

Comment: Probably fixed with https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7379

Comment: @mark : $class will use instance of $key.?

Comment: I had a [similar "missing key" error in CakePHP 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041587/how-to-define-flashhelper-component-element-for-general-autherror-message), but it was related to the **authentication** flash message - maybe the answer there is also helpful for your problem...